# How to copy one variable into another and make them independent from each other

Tags: ruby

I have a var arrays.

```
arrays = [[15, 2, 3], [9, 1, 2], [5, 3, 0]]
```

Copy it into new var sorted. Expected result is

```
[[15, 2, 3], [9, 1, 2], [5, 3, 0]]
[[2, 3, 15], [1, 2, 9], [0, 3, 5]]
```

I can't sort var sorted without changing var arrays

```
sorted_clone = arrays.clone

sorted_clone.each do |i|
  i.sort!
end

p arrays
p sorted_clone
```

I've also tried

```
arrays = [[15, 2, 3], [9, 1, 2], [5, 3, 0]]

sorted_dup = arrays.dup

sorted_dup.each do |i|
  i.sort!
end

p arrays
p sorted_dup
```

The result for both is the same

```
[[2, 3, 15], [1, 2, 9], [0, 3, 5]]
[[2, 3, 15], [1, 2, 9], [0, 3, 5]]
```

Comment: Use `map` and a new assignment perhaps.

Comment: A "deep copy" `obj1` of an object `obj0` has the property that no change to `obj1` alters `obj0`.  As @Jokester's answer demonstrates, making a deep copy of an array of arrays is quite straightforward. Sometimes, however, you need to make a deep copy of a complex object `obj0`, such as when you have multi-level nesting of arrays and hashes. One way to do that (for most objects) is to use methods from the [Marshal](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Marshal.html) module: `obj1 = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(obj0))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to do one-level-deeper clone, i.e. duplicate child items as well.

```
arrays = [[15, 2, 3], [9, 1, 2], [5, 3, 0]]

sorted_clone = arrays.map {|item| item.clone}

sorted_clone.each do |i|
    i.sort!
end

p arrays
p sorted_clone
```

Another way is to create new objects, instead of mutating existing ones:

```
arrays = [[15, 2, 3], [9, 1, 2], [5, 3, 0]]

# #sort method is the not-modifying-in-place version of #sort!
sorted_clone = arrays.map {|child| child.sort }

p arrays
p sorted_clone
```